# Get bound URLs from within a Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'd like to display my web server's bound URLs from within a Razor Pages view.  I can access them from within `Main` like so:

```
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    //...
    var app = builder.Build();
    //...
    await app.StartAsync();
    //...
    // Debug here...
```

... by having a breakpoint at "Debug here" and examining `app.Urls` (app is a `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication`), but I can't add this during the DI configuration because it only gets populated after `StartAsync`.  How, then, can I get access to this information from within a Razor Pages view running from within that web application?

Comment: Take a look at this link and search for "How to get ASP.NET Core server URLs using Dependency Injection". It shows how to get them in a controller method. If that works, then you could simply pass the values to your views from there. https://swimburger.net/blog/dotnet/how-to-get-aspdotnet-core-server-urls

Comment: It talks about using `IServerAddressesFeature`, which I've read is no longer automatically populated, so I don't think it'd work anymore.

Comment: Which ASP.NET Core version are you using?

Comment: I'm using .NET 7.

Comment: Can you show how you are retrieving IServerAddressesFeature? Because it should still be populated in .NET 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom configuration class to hold the URLs.

```
public class WebServerUrls
{
    public List<string> Urls { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

In your `Program.cs` file, add the registration for this custom configuration class as a singleton service:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WebServerUrls>();
// ...


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// ...

var app = builder.Build();
// ...

await app.StartAsync();
var webServerUrls = app.Services.GetRequiredService<WebServerUrls>();
webServerUrls.Urls.AddRange(app.Urls);

// ...
```

In your Razor Pages view, inject the WebServerUrls class using the @inject directive and access the bound URLs:

```
@page
@model YourPageModel

@inject WebServerUrls WebServerUrls

<h1>Bound URLs</h1>

<ul>
    @foreach (var url in WebServerUrls.Urls)
    {
        <li>@url</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: Right, so delayed resolution basically.  Do you think that class would need some kind of mutex lock around access to the list of Urls to deal with race conditions?

Comment: Yes, you should consider adding synchronization mechanisms like a mutex or a lock to ensure thread safety when accessing the list of URLs, especially in a multi-threaded environment.

Answer (score 2):

To display the web server's bound URLs within a Razor Pages view, create a service to store and access this information then inject that service data into Razor view.

*service*:

```
public class WebServerInfoService : IWebServerInfoService
{
    private readonly List<string> boundUrls = new List<string>();
    private readonly object lockObject = new object();

    public void AddBoundUrl(string url)
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            boundUrls.Add(url);
        }
    }

    public List<string> GetBoundUrls()
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            return boundUrls.ToList(); // Return a copy of the list to prevent modification by consumers
        }
    }
}
```

*Main:*

```
 app.UseUrls(urls =>
    {
        foreach (var url in urls)
        {
            webServerInfoService.AddBoundUrl(url);
        }
    });
```

*Razor View:*

```
@inject IWebServerInfoService webServerInfoService

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bound URLs</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Bound URLs</h1>
    <ul>
        @foreach (var url in webServerInfoService.GetBoundUrls())
        {
            <li>@url</li>
        }
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Right, so delayed resolution basically.  Do you think that class would need some kind of mutex lock around access to the list of Urls to deal with race conditions?

Comment: @Jez Yes, should use some form of synchronization, such as a mutex lock, to handle potential race conditions when multiple threads or requests access the boundUrls list concurrently. Without synchronization, there's a risk of data corruption or unexpected behavior when multiple threads attempt to add or retrieve URLs simultaneously. 
the answer is updated please check...